# Disallow uploading of the same build to Fabric Beta (crashlytics)

Tags: android, crashlytics, fastlane, bitrise, fabric-beta

I am working on an app which can automatically deploy to beta-services (we use Testflight for iOS and Fabric Beta for Android). The entire deployment-process is run over BitRise, using fastlane-commands, and is set up to make an internal build & release when a merge with the develop-branch happens.

On Testflight a new build MUST Have a different version-number - which is useful, so we can determine at which point we want to have a new beta-release.

On Fabric Beta however the system can "overwrite" an old version with the same number, and will then send out an email to all testers saying "There is a new version! It's -old_version-" - which means for every minor merge/pull we do there will be a new build made, uploaded to Fabric Beta, will overwrite the previous one (with the same version number & version code), and inform all testers that there is a new version available, which confusingly has the same name as the previous one.

Is there a way to check in fastlane-crashlytics-uploader if a build already exists and then NOT to do it, or an option hidden somewhere in Fabric to not allow uploads in that case?